# Create Java objects more directly from JSON with JsonPath

Tags: java, jsonpath

I create Objects from JsonPath with

```java
List<String> httpList = JsonPath.read(json, "$.*.http_url_to_repo");
List<String> idList = JsonPath.read(json, "$.*.id");

for (int i = 0; i < httpList.size(); i++)
{
    back.add(new GitlabProject(httpList.get(i), idList.get(i)));
}
```

Is there a more direct way to create the `GitlabProject` objects from the JSON?

The JSON looks like

```json
[
    {
        "id": 63,
        "description": null,
        "name": "conti-maven-plugin-mm",
        "name_with_namespace": "ik / spu / other / conti-maven-plugin-mm",
        "path": "conti-maven-plugin-mm",
        "path_with_namespace": "ik/spu/other/conti-maven-plugin-mm",
        "created_at": "2023-01-30T12:33:59.218Z",
        "default_branch": "main",
        "tag_list": [],
        "topics": [],
        "ssh_url_to_repo": "git@gitlab-test.continentale.loc:ik/spu/other/conti-maven-plugin-mm.git",
        "http_url_to_repo": "https://gitlab-test.continentale.loc/ik/spu/other/conti-maven-plugin-mm.git",
        "web_url": "https://gitlab-test.continentale.loc/ik/spu/other/conti-maven-plugin-mm",
        ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your POJO has different property names:

```
public class GitlabProject {
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty("http_url_to_repo")
    private String httpUrlToRepo;
    // Constructor, getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Use ObjectMapper from the Jackson library to deserialize the JSON array into a list of GitlabProject objects:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<GitlabProject> projects = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<GitlabProject>>(){});
```

You can do similar thing using Google's GSON library.

```
List<GitlabProject> projects = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<GitlabProject>>(){}.getType());
```

Not that you'll need to use @SerializedName if property name is different in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using JsonPath itself directly.
Just define a custom mapping function.

```
List<GitlabProject> projects = JsonPath.parse(json)
    .read("$[*]", list -> list.stream()
        .map(obj -> {
            String httpUrl = JsonPath.read(obj, "$.http_url_to_repo");
            int id = JsonPath.read(obj, "$.id");
            return new GitlabProject(httpUrl, id);
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

- "$[*]" - selects all elements in the JSON array
- The lamda expression    inside "read" method extracts all
  "http_url_to_repo" and "id" values    from JSON and creates
  corresponding "GitlabProject".
- Finally the list    of objects are created using
  "Collectors.toList()"

Comment: Sorry, there seems to be a compiler problem in the code: `[175,39] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method stream()
[ERROR]   location: variable list of type com.jayway.jsonpath.Predicate.PredicateContext`